# Save to a LinkedHashSet <String> - BEGINNER

Tags: java, mysql, list, linkedhashset

```
@Override
public LinkedHashSet <String> listHotels() {
   Query query  = em.createNativeQuery("select  * from Hotel");
   LinkedHashSet <String> hotel= query.getResultList();
   return hotel;
}
```

I am getting a Warning saying `incompatible types. query.getResultList(); returns a List`, but what I want the method to return is a `LinkedHashSet`.

The reason why I'm using a `LinkedHashSet` here, is to avoid duplicate values being entered to the DB. I will call the method `listHotels()` first, and check if it has already contains the value and if doesn't I'll save the values to the DB

**EDIT**

```
    public void saveHotel(Hotel hotel) {
    if (hotel.getId() ==null){
        em.persist(hotel);
    } else {
        em.merge(hotel);
    }
}
```

THis is how i save records to my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not map a List to a Set. If you just want to eliminate duplicate then you can do so using your DB query

Comment: How should i do that. I have added the code where i save the record to the DB. Help

Comment: To get distinct hotels, you can just say - "Select distinct HotelNames from hotels order by HotelNames;"

Comment: But, I want to prevent writing duplicate records to the DB

Comment: @Illep, a select query does not prevent duplicate records. If you are concerned with duplicate records, you should prevent them in the insert/update part and with a unique constraint on the database

Comment: Yes. If you dont want to write duplicate records, just add a unique constraint to your DB. If it is not possible then use the Set instead of list.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the result type of query.getResultList(), but you can *convert* the List to a `LinkedHashSet`:

```
LinkedHashSet<String> hotel= new LinkedHashSet(query.getResultList());
```

(The LinkedHashSet created will have the unique elements from the list. But the example you have shown is a SELECT sql, rather than an INSERT/UPDATE. To guarantee unique records on the database, you have to make such an arrangement - using a LinkedHashSet or so - in the INSERT/UPDATE part. If you are already using a `LinkedHashSet` to add to the database, the database won't have duplicate records anyway. BTW, you have the necessary unique constraints on the database right?)